# Être la cause de ou être cause de?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation, reformulation

> La nostalgie des jours heureux est cause de sa dépression.

> La nostalgie des jours heureux est la cause de sa dépression.

Quelle est la cause de sa dépression ?

> La nostalgie des jours heureux en est cause.

> La nostalgie des jours heureux en est la cause.

Il semble, à l’oreille à tout le moins, qu’elle se dise mieux avec l’article *la* dans la seconde formule. Qu’en pensez-vous? Il est vrai que la question frise la subjectivité (j’en suis conscient), en revanche il me paraît légitime qu’on me fournisse une réponse relative à la construction de la phrase citée dans le contexte de la question (avec ou sans déterminant de préférence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I** « Être cause de » prend un sens particulier en raison de l'absence d'article.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/cause/13860)) occasionner, provoquer quelque chose
> ♦︎ Les pluies sont cause de graves inondations.

Donc la première phrase se comprendrait comme suit.

> La nostalgie des jours heureux occasionne/provoque sa dépression.

Ce n'est pas le cas. Si l'on change le temps, la phrase devient vraie, et on dit pratiquement la même chose.

> La nostalgie des jours heureux a occasionné/ a provoqué sa dépression.

**II** La réponse directe à cette question est « C'est la nostalgie des jours heureux. » ou « La nostalgie des jours heureux. »

D'après « I », puisque dans la question il ne s'agit pas de l'expression figée, il faut préserver l'article dans la réponse, et on peut dire ceci.

- La nostalgie des jours heureux en est la cause.

La reprise du verbe « être » et des autres mots de la question est perçu comme répétitif, à moins que le locuteur adopte une certaine intonation en vue de communiquer une nuance, d'habitude une certaine emphase, comme lorsque l'interlocuteur devrait savoir et qu'il ne pose pas la question à bon escient; on accentue alors la partie « La nostalgie des jours heureux » et on prononce « en est la cause » avec un ton de voix plus bas.